# RDP on Windows10 for RaspberryPi

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi2

How can I activate Remote Desktop Protocol on Windows10 through commandline?

I have the SSH running from Mac to Win10, but are not get RDP working.

I tried this CMD command for activation:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Rebooted with:

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

And looked for listening ports with:

```
netstat /p tcp /a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 IoT Core doesn't support RDP up to now.
The only "remote" ways are :

Powershell
SSH
Web Interface

Paolo.